# PHP scandir returns incorrect filenames

Tags: php

`scandir(some path)` is giving incorrect filenames.

When I do a ls of the folder, I get results like

```
selected0_LjRNXtMpXn4_0:0:0.mp4      selected8054_YdZl86snmag_0:2:32.mp4
selected10_iJTkxI6WMbo_0:2:20.mp4    selected8056_jgABBaXQSK8_0:3:40.mp4
```

However, scandir is returning the following:

```
S4XFWK~B.MP4
SDTP6P~D.MP4
SHTYF1~M.MP4
SX8WCA~J.MP4
```

I have double and triple checked to make sure that I am `ls`-ing and `scandir`-ing the same folder. Why is `scandir` not returning correct filenames?

Update: Machine running scandir is a windows server 2008 enterprise, machine the files are stored on is running fedora 20, with disk type fuse.glusterfs

Comment: It is, but it returns the filename like it is stored on disk. ls shows you the extended "real" name. A long time ago filenames could not have longer names than 8 characters.

Comment: What kind of system, and more importantly file system, are these coming from? Those 8.3 names are almost, but not quite, what Windows generates for long filenames (I've not seen letters rather than digits after the `~` before). Is this a SAMBA fileshare or similar?

Comment: @IMSoP How do I check? Also, I pasted a subset of all the files: some of the files do end with a digit after the ~, ex `SHO16G~9.MP4`

Comment: Windows server 2008 enterprise on the system running scandir

Comment: Files come from a machine running fedora 20, df--print-type says the type is fuse.glusterfs

Comment: OK, that's a pretty exotic combination of systems. I would suggest adding some details of how that is all configured into the question - are the files mounted on the Fedora box, and then made available to Windows via Samba or similar share? Or are both configured to point to the GlusterFS storage?

Comment: Also, I'm assuming the `ls` output is from the Fedora box. What happens if you use `dir` on the Windows box?

Comment: @IMSoP I get the 8.3 filenames

Comment: @KevinL OK, so that rules out PHP as part of the problem, doesn't it? It sounds like it's something to do with the way the files are made accessible to the Windows box from GlusterFS or the Linux box. Since it's more of a sysadmin question, I suggest you take this question to either http://SuperUser.com or http://ServerFault.com

Comment: gah, wish this stuff would just magically work. thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer. The filenames when viewed from a linux system had a colon `:` in them, which isn't a valid windows filename, so they were replaced with the 8.3 names.